# Windows Event Viewer and log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

I have idea to write errors from my application to the **Windows Event Viewer** using **log4net**. Can I do it or not? And if I can, how :). 
Thank you.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

log4net supports a [EventLogAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-2.0.7/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_EventLogAppender.htm) so, yes, you can do it. How? You can start by checking the log4net [configuration examples](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#eventlogappender) for that appender.

If you encounter any specific problem you can update your question with more details so people can help you better.

Comment: In Event Viewer >> Windows Logs >> Application. Then filter/scroll for entries where the source is the one configured in the EventLogAppender log4net appender configuration using <applicationName value="xxx"/>.