# How to write entries to Windows Event Viewer by log4net in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, log4net, xmlconfigurator

I have read [this article.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial) and this [answer1SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618380/log4net-does-not-write-the-log-file), [answer2SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523252/log4net-doesnt-log-in-windows-event-viewer), [answer3SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598681/windows-event-viewer-and-log4net).

What I've done so far:

**1. Declared in the last line of  AssemblyInfo.cs :**

```
    [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

**2. Written in app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

**3. What I've written in my handler:**

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   XmlConfigurator.Configure();       
   ILog Log = 
   LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
   Log.Fatal("The exception occurred", new Exception("Hello World of event log")); 
}`
```

After all these three implemented actions, I have no entries in my Window Event Viewer. Please, see my Window Event Viewer:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app needs to run once as Administrator to create the event source that the logs will be assigned to: see ["Why doesn't the EventLogAppender work?"](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#trouble-EventLog) in the log4net documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I am an administrator at my PC, but I'll try on Monday to run my program with administrative privileges.

Comment: @StepUp you need to use "Run as Administrator" explictly, rather than just as a user in the admin group

Comment: that is action of simple users cannot be logged to Window Event Viewer? actions of not administrators could not be logged to Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: No, it's _creating the event source_ that needs to be done by 'administrator' - after that, users can write to the event log using that event source.

Comment: So is it possible to write to event viewer without running "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: Yes it is, as long as the event source exists

Comment: consequently, the first run of program at new PC must be run always as "Run as Administrator?"

Comment: Or you can add ithe event source as part of your installation program.

Comment: How can I do it? Maybe you have a link?

Comment: Do you already have an installer? How are you distributing the program?

Comment: using Windows Setup Project.

Comment: man, you are magic!:) Could not upvote more than one time!:) Thanks!:)